# Angular UI Router state.go and anchor tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The following element:

```
<p ng-click="$state.go('state.a',{id: 'subsection-b'})">Click me</p>
```

is (when clicked) only navigating to the top of my state.a page and not scrolling down to the

`<p id="subsection-b">...</p>`

element on that page.

Why is that and what do I need to modify to get anchor tags to work with state.go? (BTW I know how to solve it with `ui-sref` but I need it to work with state.go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` in `$state.go('state.a',{id: 'subsection-b'})"` is a state parameter! It's not an html ID attribute.

for that you should use state url:

```
<a href="[state_url] + #subsection-b"><p>Click me</p></a>
```

that [state-_url] is the url you set for state in its definition.

Comment: Thanks for the state parameter explanation, but I still don't understand what X in $state.go('X') should be in order to get it to work.

Comment: You can't link to specific id in a page with `$state.go()`.

Comment: @Mahmoud, `$state.go(tab, {'#': anchor})`

Comment: @Andrew much rather do that then specify url

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that needs the ui-sref syntax:

```
ui-sref="page({name: 'name', '#': 'frag'})"
```

Also, as Andrew Tobilko correctly points out, the syntax for the $state.go function uses a hash (#) not 'id':

```
$state.go('page', {name: 'name', '#': 'frag'})
```

**Note:** This requires ui-router v0.2.14 or higher.

Source: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1867